# Google place API not working some time

Tags: ios, iphone, google-places-api, google-places

I am using the Google place API for nearest place around my location.  But some times Google place API returns the error

```
{
    "error_message" = "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.";
    "html_attributions" =     (
    );
    results =     (
    );
    status = "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT";
}
```

I know that this message is shown when my usage limit is exceeded, however, my usage limit is 100000 per day and the API shows the error before the limit is reached.

Any idea??

Comment: Are you sure you're not sending more than 10 requests / second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is limit for daily queries (requests).